# Why does the borrow checker not understand that borrowing different parts of a slice is fundamentally okay?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The `split_at_mut` function (for splitting mutable slices at an index) requires unsafe code ([according to the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html#creating-a-safe-abstraction-over-unsafe-code)) to be implemented. But the book also says: "Borrowing different parts of a slice is fundamentally okay because the two slices aren’t overlapping".

**My question:** Why does the borrow checker not understand that borrowing different parts of a slice is fundamentally okay? (Is there a reason preventing the borrow checker from understanding this rule or is it just that it has not been implemented for some reason?)

Trying the suggested code with Rust 1.48 still results in the error shown in the book:

```
fn split_at_mut(slice: &mut [i32], mid: usize) -> (&mut [i32], &mut [i32]) {
    let len = slice.len();

    assert!(mid <= len);

    (&mut slice[..mid], &mut slice[mid..])
}

fn main() {
    let mut vector = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    let (left, right) = split_at_mut(&mut vector, 3);
    println!("{:?}, {:?}", left, right);
}
```

Gives error message:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*slice` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:6:30
  |
1 | fn split_at_mut(slice: &mut [i32], mid: usize) -> (&mut [i32], &mut [i32]) {
  |                        - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
6 |     (&mut slice[..mid], &mut slice[mid..])
  |     -------------------------^^^^^--------
  |     |     |                  |
  |     |     |                  second mutable borrow occurs here
  |     |     first mutable borrow occurs here
  |     returning this value requires that `*slice` is borrowed for `'1`
```

Comment: I'm sure you're already aware of this and were just asking for a better understanding of the borrow checker, but for future readers it's probably worth noting that the slice primitive does of course provide a safe [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) method (but which, like much of the standard library, is implemented with unsafe operations to overcome this problem).

Answer (score 12):

> Why does the borrow checker not understand that borrowing different parts of a slice is fundamentally okay?

Because it's impossible to do generally. Sure, in this case it's obvious that `&slice[..mid]` and `&slice[mid..]` are disjoint, but the complexity skyrockets once you escape trivial cases and it quickly becomes impossible.

These special trivial cases aren't implemented specially because:

1. Having a language feature that allows obviously disjoint slice borrows but not anything even slightly more complicated is unintuitive and can make beginners think they can do more things than they actually can
2. These special cases really only boil down to a couple patterns, most of which can be accomplished with [`split_at`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at) and its mutable counterpart
3. There's no way to reliably extend this to anything with the [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) trait, which means that `(&slice[..mid], &slice[mid..])` would be valid but `(&vec[..mid], &vec[mid..])` wouldn't be, which is even more inconsistent. Of course this could be solved by making `Vec` a language intrinsic, but then what about `VecDeque` or user-defined data structures? It just leads to too much inconsistency that spirals into more inconsistency, which is something that Rust wants to avoid.

Comment: Basically the compiler would have to store which ranges of the slice are already borrowed to decide this, which could get quite complicated/impossible depending on the datatype.

Comment: Storing ranges isn't possible if the indices aren't constants known at compile time.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how vector slices complicate the picture? Are string slices and vector slices not both references to array underneath the hood? VecDeque does not support slicing because of possible wrap-around, but does support turning into a pair of slices, which are again array references.

Comment: VecDeque still supports individual indexing, which may lead to things like `&vecdeque[0]` and `&vecdeque[1]` being disallowed despite clearly being valid. `Vec` is an entirely custom data structure, and vector slices work by [implementing the `Index` trait for ranges](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Index%3CI%3E).

Answer (score 2):

Rust’s borrow checker can’t understand that you’re borrowing different parts of the slice; it only knows that you’re borrowing from the same slice twice. What if the two slices are overlapping? There's no way to grantee that their not. (If there is, it isn't implemented yet)

That's why unsafe exists: when you know for sure that there's no way that your code will produce an unexpected behavior despite the compiler not being able to grantee that.

Comment: *"Rust’s borrow checker can’t understand that you’re borrowing different parts of the slice"* - I'm not sure this is accurate. With `(&mut slice[..mid], &mut slice[mid..])` it's obvious, at compile time, that the slices don't overlap. I understand, that this is not true in general, but in this specific case that reasoning isn't convincing.

Comment: This is rather special. A pure syntactic analysis would fail for this pattern `(&mut slice[..mid], dec(&mut mid), &mut slice[mid..])` (given that dec decreases the argument by 1). So a constraint solver on ranges bound to each expression used as range or index of an array is needed. But solving these constraints in general is undecidable, so `unsafe` will be needed anyway. Also an incomplete solver can get quite expensive if one incorporate intraprocedural constraints.

Comment: @IInspectable It's obvious to you, but not to the compiler, which must be able to handle arbitrarily complex slicing expressions. Proving that they don't overlap in the general case is equivalent to the halting problem i.e. theoretically impossible. For the trivial case where the slice is split by a middle element there is `split_at_mut` which removes the need to special-case this in the compiler.

Comment: @use I'm not questioning that there were valid reasons. Just pointing out that this proposed answer doesn't attempt to answer the specific question. Your comment is far more useful in making a convincing argument.